# Adding delete button to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going to add a delete button to new items made. This delete button removes the item my-item from the page without affecting others.

Code I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Demo</title>
    <style>
      .my-item{
      width:250px;
      heigth:180px;
      margin:10px;
      padding:20px;
      background:green;
      border:2px solid black;
      }
      .item-header{
      width:150px;
      heigth:120px;
      margin:5px;
      padding:10px;
      background:yellow;
      border:1px solid black;
      }
      .item-body{
      width:70px;
      heigth:50px;
      margin:3px;
      padding:5px;
      background:purple;
      border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#divButton").click(function(){
          $(".my-item").clone().appendTo("body")

          });

          $("#toggle").click(function(){
            if ($(".item-body").is(":visible")){
              $(".item-body").slideUp("normal");
            }else{
              $(".item-body").slideDown("normal");
            }
          });

          $("#deleteButton").click(function(){
            $(".my-item").append(".my-item"+ "button        class="deleteButton">Delete</button>");
          });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="my-item">
      <div class="item-header">
        <h2 id="toggle">Click Me!</h2>
        <div class="item-body">My Text!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="divButton">Click!</button>
    <button id="deleteButton">Delete!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'll be glad if you can help me. :)

Comment: What is not working? What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: btw... I cannot get the logic of your code. When I click on the delete button jQuery will try (with a wrong code) to append a delete button??

Comment: without this part : $("#deleteButton").click(function(){
            $(".my-item").append(".my-item"+ "button        class="deleteButton">Delete</button>");
          });.    I can add new items and now I`m gonna make a delete button for the new item that when I click on it , it should remove the item my-item but the others are not affected.

Answer (score 2):

As simple as that :

```
$(".my-item").remove();
```

(if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: where to put this code? and what about this part: $("#deleteButton").click(function(){
            $(".my-item").append(".my-item"+ "button        class="deleteButton">Delete</button>");
          });   ?     I don`t know if I`m doing correctly!

Comment: What you wrote just add a new button (see the append ?), and I guess that it not really work (your button is not correctly written).
Just replace your line 
$(".my-item").append(".my-item"+ "button class="deleteButton">Delete</button>");
by my answer :)

Comment: you`re right but when I run your code and I click on delete button, it deletes all the divs, while I need to keep the first one intact and just add a delete button to each new item that it can removes the item my-item withoiy affecting others

Comment: I am sorry I can't understand your question. Do you want to delete my-item or do you want to add a new delete button ?

Comment: I need to add a button Delete to each new item (not to the first one). By clicking on this button, the corresponding item my-item, including item-header and item-body, is removed from the page, while the others are not affected. "I`m sorry to confuse you but this is what I`m going to do"

Comment: Ok do you want to have a delete button for each my-item and clicking this button delete the corresponding my-item and not the other. Am I right ?

Comment: So you should have a delete button per my-item. You can add the button inside my-item and delete the parent. Or create a different id per my-item and delete the corresponding my-item per id.

Comment: or you could use my method :) I included a delete button for each "my-item" and it'll delete the corresponding item.

Comment: @Jorrex up voted your answer. I just hope that it is what OP is trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found some things which could be improved.
First of all. An `id` is unique, so whenever you start to clone elements, the `id` is cloned as well.

I made a few adjustments and this is how it works:

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="item-header">
    <h2 id="toggle">Click Me!</h2>
    <div class="item-body">My Text!
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="divButton">Click!</button>
  <button class="deleteButton">Delete!</button>
</div>
```

**CSS** (still the same)

```
.my-item {
  width: 250px;
  heigth: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.item-header {
  width: 150px;
  heigth: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-body {
  width: 70px;
  heigth: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: purple;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function addEvents() {
  $(".divButton").unbind("click").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().clone().appendTo($("body"));
    addEvents();
  });

  $(".deleteButton").unbind("click").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
}

addEvents();
```

The reason why I put both click events in a separate function, is when the element is cloned, the events are not cloned. Therefor, you will have to rebind them. This doesn't have to happen when you delete an element.

I hope this solves your question

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/f66qfwbr/)

Comment: if this is the answer you were searching for, please mark it as the chosen answer. This helps other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you mean something like this:

```
$("#deleteButton").click(function(){
   $(this).nextAll(".my-item").remove();
});
```

This will remove all .my-item after the delete button and not your template.

Just a notice, when you're cloning your .my-item element, you'll get multiple "toggle" IDs in the DOM, which is not good.

Comment: it's an issue that will break your code to work more than just being "no good". IDs are unique!!!

Comment: @theColaKid: it should not remove all the my-item whereas each my-iem should have its own delete button which does not affect others.

Comment: I just omitted 'All' and now it works. thanks a million for your help. :) and about the notice you said I just agree with you but I don`t know how to avoid that?!

Comment: @Mahtab: Check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use single instead of the double quotation marks for js:

```
$('selector');
```

**The following line is wrong:**

```
$(".my-item").append(".my-item"+ "button class="deleteButton">Delete</button>");
```

**Correct is:**

```
$(".my-item").append("<button class=\"deleteButton\">Delete</button>");
```

or

```
$('.my-item').append('<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button>');
```

Your code will not produce new elements by clicking on button "Click!" and adding new delete buttons by clicking on the "Delete"-Button.

I guess what you want to archive is to duplicate an Item and add a delete button to the item itself.

Just clone your element without appending and save it to a var.
( var newElement = $.('selectpr').clone(); )

Then append the delete button to the newElement object and append the object to the target.

Another approach would be appending the clone to a container and then selecting it by looking for the last element in the container. Then bind a click event to the delete button.

Please check jQuery and CSS manual for correct selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a different solution for you with cached element and no duplicate IDs.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $myItem = $(".my-item");
        var $deleteBtn = $("<button/>",{"class":"deleteButton"}).text('Delete').on({
            click: function() {
                $(this).closest('.my-item').remove();   // delete item
            }
        });

        // enable toggle of item body
        $(".toggle").click(function() {
            $(this).next(".item-body").slideToggle("normal");
        });

        // Add new item
        $("#divButton").click(function(){
            var $newItem = $myItem.clone(true);
            $("body").append($newItem.append($deleteBtn.clone(true)));
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is your HTML body part:

```
<body>
    <div class="my-item">
        <div class="item-header">
            <h2 class="toggle">Click Me!</h2>
            <div class="item-body">My Text!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="divButton">Click!</button>
</body>
```